# What points should I mention and how? - in a theory paper's introduction part

Tags: paper-review

this is my first time writing a theory paper and I am getting carried away with thoughts when I am writing theory paper's introduction, I have read some web pages telling what points should I mention but I am still confused on how to mention them? like using maths? examples? or just textual theory? its so confusing that it gave me headache.
So here I am asking what should I mention in my theory paper's introduction and how?

Comment: This might be too broad and difficult to answer generically...maybe you have a mentor or can ask someone who has published theory papers before? And you can look at published papers for examples of how such introductions are commonly written.

Comment: @usul , I did look at papers published before got some help from there and yeah I am looking for mentor, if you got any advice then feel free to post.

Comment: I can try: think of the reader as an expert in the field. They want to know exactly what problem you are studying, what is the challenge that needs to be overcome, how this relates to prior work results, what the results of the paper are, and the main new ideas behind the results (like a proof technique). Usually these should all be covered to some extent so as to be interesting to an expert, but also accessible to a general theory audience. [Don't take this as written in stone, but hope it helps.]

Comment: Writing an introduction is a skill that takes time, experimentation and experience to develop. My suggestion is to start with a simple and straight forward introduction that sticks to the basics: problem addressed, main results, and a brief overview of related work. See how it looks and refine as needed and/or check with a more experienced person such as an advisor or more senior student who has written papers in the past.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri 
here is a funny fact, my idea is brand new (as far as I can see). No one has ever done this in the field of Artifcial Intelligence, so what am I suppose to write in related work? like Neural Networks can be compared with Genetic algorithm upto certain point but mine doesn't. The problem I am mentioning does exist but no one ever tried to solve it because its either too hard to solve or they never paid attention to it. So you see here I am bringing light to a hidden problem that is like an Easter egg, solving this will change the A.I field dramatically.

Comment: @usul read the upper comment ^

Comment: If I were you and were talking about a field I am not an expert on I would be more humble about any claims of break-through: probably there are mistakes or oversights in the work, probably missing some previous work, probably misunderstanding the problem, etc.

Comment: See [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18491/)

Comment: @kaveh I am expert in my field, its just that I have never written a theory paper before as I have never made a theory before of my own, because theory isn't a often thing, deep work makes something new and probably amazing. I have checked on my work/idea/theory with a Polish Scientist but as he is polish he can't help me with my work very well. So I am asking for a layout or outline so that I don't look like a fool when I present my paper to some Global Elites

Comment: Eventually it will not be enough that you think your ideas are new, you will have to convince your peers. One route is to show your preprint to other experts who are willing to provide you feedback.

Comment: @VijayD , oh they will provide feed back , they will hahaha, I know darn well what I got in my idea.